# No such element: Unable to locate element OpenQA.Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am facing this exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"#MuliCloudAccountSelector"}

My Code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("MuliCloudAccountSelector")).Click();
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="MuliCloudAccountSelector" class="antd-pro-src-components-page-header-wrapper-multi-account-selector-antpopover" style="border: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217); margin-left: 6px; margin-right: 10px; height: 40px; float: left; min-width: 24px; border-radius: 4px; max-width: 316px; overflow: hidden;">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it is because of the page rendering delay? I would try to insert a sleep command before the click command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the element to be clickable:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(drive, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var div = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("MuliCloudAccountSelector"));

div.Click();
```

There is likely a race condition occurring between Selenium and the browser. You are finding the element before the element is rendered in the page.

Comment: Now I am facing this exception:                              
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54956/session/348b48f3a473ec89625cecf50b643271/url timed out after 60 seconds.'

Comment: @Saher: That seems like a different issue. Web browsers like to auto-update to a newer version. You'll need to check that your web browser version is properly supported by the Web Driver you are using.